# incorrect results from for

Tags: xml, xslt, xerces

I am processing xml using two xsl files using xerces, and getting wrong results in my xsl:for-each loop,
the for loop return 8 results instead of 4 results
How can debug this error?
Thanks for your help!

The xml:

```
<Updates>
  <update_record displayTimestamp="2013-03-08 11:44:00">
    <user>MNM3322</user>
  </update_record>
  <update_record displayTimestamp="2013-03-08 11:45:00">
    <user>MNM3323</user>
  </update_record>
  <update_record displayTimestamp="2013-03-08 11:46:00">
    <user>MNM3322</user>
  </update_record>
  <update_record displayTimestamp="2013-03-08 11:47:00">
    <user>MNM3325</user>
  </update_record>
  <LatestUpdate/>
</Updates>
```

first.xsl

```
<xsl:variable name="updates" select="//Updates"/>
```

second.xsl

```
<xsl:variable name="updatesCount"
              select="count($updates/update_record)"/>

<xsl:include href="first.xsl"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$updatesCount"/>  this gives correct result (4)
<xsl:for-each select="$updates/update_record"> this gives incorrect output (8 rows instead of 4)
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Does your source document have more than one `Updates` element? Where is `$updatesCount` defined?

Comment: there is just one Updates element - I edit to include the updatesCount

Comment: Does your XSLT shown above output "12345678" for the `for-each`, or "12341234", or something else?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. Either there's something you haven't shown us, or you're misinterpreting the output, or (very unlikely) you've got a buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: yes - output is 12345678    ,  XERCES version is Xerces-J 2.7.1 Xalan java 2.7.0

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the output you say you're getting, from a stylesheet containing the XSLT fragments you provide, running (with Xalan 2.7.1) on the input you provide.  If you're getting that output, you're getting it on different input or with a different stylesheet.  So: check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. its XALAN Bug


See here:

Circular variable/parameter reference if recursive template is used in global variable


https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2430

Thank you!